# Syntax error on ALTER COLUMN - Ingres

Tags: sql, ingres

I have an sql script that I am running in via PUTTY to update an ingres DB

It is having errors with the following query (which work fine in Squirell SQL Client)

```
ALTER TABLE address 
ALTER COLUMN address2 VARCHAR(100); \p\g
```

Where I am trying to alter the address 2 column to allow for more characters.

It displays

> E_US0F0A line 1, Syntax error on 'ALTER COLUMN'.  The correct syntax
>   is:
>
> ALTER TABLE tablename
>            ADD [CONSTRAINT constraint_name] constraint_clause
>          | DROP CONSTRAINT constraint_name RESTRICT | CASCADE
>          | ADD [COLUMN] columnname format [default_clause] [null_clause]
>       [column_constraint]    | DROP [COLUMN] column_name RESTRICT | CASCADE

It seems ingres only allows for add or drop.

Comment: Ingres doesn't appear to support modifying a column.  You can drop the column and add it again.

Comment: Does this mean I would lose all the data in the column? There is thousands of data entries.

Comment: Rename it first then create a new column and copy the old data,then drop it

Comment: Ingres doesn't support rename either Error: line 1, Syntax error on 'RENAME'.  The correct syntax is: bla bla ADD DROP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too long for a comment.  You need to:

1. Add a new temp column with the right type.
2. Update the temp column with the old value.
3. Drop the old column.
4. Add a new column with the right name and type.
5. Update the new column with the value from the temp column.
6. Drop the temp column.

A bit cumbersome.

Comment: Thanks i'll accept this as the answer. I'm getting an error E_QE009D Alter Table ADD/DROP column support for pages greater than 2k
only. but thats a different issue